# What is the difference between AccessLevel.PACKAGE and AccessLevel.MODULE?

Tags: java, lombok

In Lombok, what is the actual difference between

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
private int country;
```

and

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.MODULE)
private int country;
```

?

Comment: Package for package (ie folder). Module is for java 9 modules I suppose

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That *is* a good question. I tried creating some setters for some test methods and all I got was (decompiled):

```
for Module AccessLevel:
void setTestModule(Integer testModule) {
    this.testModule = testModule;
}

for Package AccessLevel:
void setTestPackage(Integer testPackage) {
    this.testPackage = testPackage;
}
```

So, on first look it appears that there is no difference. So, I looked into the source code and all I could verify is that for the time being they are handled the same (from the source [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok)):

> lombok.javac.handlers.JavacHandlerUtil.toJavacModifier(AccessLevel accessLevel)
>   or lombok.eclipse.handlers.EclipseHandlerUtil.toEclipseModifier(AccessLevel accessLevel)

```
/**
 * Turns an {@code AccessLevel} instance into the flag bit used by javac.
 */
public static int toJavacModifier(AccessLevel accessLevel) {
    switch (accessLevel) {
    case MODULE:
    case PACKAGE:
        return 0;
    default:
    case PUBLIC:
        return Flags.PUBLIC;
    case NONE:
    case PRIVATE:
        return Flags.PRIVATE;
    case PROTECTED:
        return Flags.PROTECTED;
    }
}
```

I think that there will be some future work on that for java 9 probably, but for now it appears to be the same.

Comment: That makes sense, I did not think about JDK9. It's probably work in progress! I'll accept your great answer if no one else comes in with additional plans or roadmaps about this. THANKS

Comment: @JadeDezo AFAIK `AccessLevel.MODULE` exists since the very beginning and was anticipating Java 9 modules. Years ago, I expected modules to be a sort of super-packages and so probably did the Lombok authors. AFAIK, this isn't the case with Java 9 and there's and probably never will be anything like `Flags.MODULE`.

Comment: @maaartinus is totally right. The lombok developers expected a different module system than we got. I think the value "MODULE" should be deprecated and eventually removed. Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: @RoelSpilker could you please shed the light what exactly is not right with java 9 modules and this value?

Comment: @RoelSpilker thanks for the insight. I am wondering if you would implement some access level that only include the class itself and its tests?